# File Save Error for Untitled.ipynb Invalid string length (file size problem?)

Tags: matplotlib, networking

I use jupyterlab 3.2 on ANACONDA.NAVIGATOR for phyton

I wordk network graph

when i run my code. loop for 21 files

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import community

def IDauthorsNetwork(ID, authors):
    idn = nx.Graph()
    for i, ids in enumerate(ID):
        for id in ids:
            if not idn.has_node(id):
                idn.add_node(id, bipartite=1, count=1)
            else:
                idn.nodes[id]['count'] += 1
        for a in authors[i]:
            if not idn.has_node(a):
                idn.add_node(a, bipartite=0, count=1)
            else:
                idn.nodes[a]['count'] += 1
            for id in ids:
                idn.add_edge(id, a, count=1)
    return idn

for year in range(2000, 2022):
    with open(f'{year}AUID.txt', 'r', encoding='cp949', errors='ignore') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    auts = []
    ids = []
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith('AU'):
            aut = [a.strip() for a in line[3:].split(',')]
            auts.append(aut)
        elif line.startswith('ID'):
            id = [i.strip() for i in line[3:].split(';')]
            ids.append(id)

    # Create the ID-author network
    idn = IDauthorsNetwork(ID=ids, authors=auts)

    # Detect communities using the Louvain algorithm
    communities = community.best_partition(idn)

    # Set the node colors based on their bipartite attribute
    node_colors = ['orange' if idn.nodes[n]['bipartite'] == 0 else 'lightblue' for n in idn.nodes()]

    # Set the node sizes based on their count attribute
    node_sizes = [2000 * idn.nodes[n]['count'] for n in idn.nodes()]

    # Set the edge widths based on their count attribute
    edge_widths = [2 * idn.edges[e]['count'] for e in idn.edges]

    # Set the font size for the node labels
    font_size = 8

    # Set the figure size and resolution
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20), dpi=800)

    # Draw the graph
    pos = nx.spring_layout(idn, k=0.2, iterations=50)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(idn, pos, node_size=node_sizes, node_color=node_colors, alpha=0.8)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(idn, pos, width=edge_widths, alpha=0.1)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(idn, pos, font_size=font_size, font_weight='bold', labels={n: n for n in idn.nodes()}, alpha=0.8)

    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig(f'{year}world.png')
    plt.show()
```

input file is txt file
structure is like this

1st txt file is 23kb

10th file is 346kb

20th file is 3782kb

```
AU Urmeneta, J
   Navarrete, A
   Sancho, J
ID NATURAL MINERAL WATERS; BACTERIAL-FLORA

AU Rasmussen, TT
   Kirkeby, LP
   Poulsen, K
   Reinholdt, J
   Kilian, M
ID RNA GENE-SEQUENCES; CORYNEBACTERIUM-ACCOLENS; PHYLOGENETIC ANALYSIS;
   ATOPIC DISEASE; SP-NOV; CHILDREN; BACTERIA; IDENTIFICATION;
   AUREOBACTERIUM; MICROBACTERIUM

AU Beniamovskii, VN

AU Efremov, AL

AU De Boever, P
   Deplancke, B
   Verstraete, W
ID HUMAN COLONIC MICROBIOTA; 16S RIBOSOMAL-RNA; SOYBEAN ISOFLAVONES;
   DIETARY MODULATION; FECAL SAMPLES; PREBIOTICS; METHANOGENESIS; BACTERIA;
   PHYTOESTROGENS; MICROFLORA
....
```

output file is png file of network graph

so when my code meet 13th file (837kb)

`File Save Error for Untitled.ipynb Invalid string length`

this error occur and saving failed

i'm not sure
but i guess it is problem about memory or something
do i have to cut some strings or parrel work?

Answer (score 1):

i just had this, i went to edit > clear all outputs. and saved.

Comment: Are you sure you had the same error? It seems strange that what you did could be a fix for that.